# Checkbox is unclickable inside div that has onclick listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox inside a div that has an onclick javascript event attached to it.

When I click on the checkbox, the onclick event is fired, instead of the checkbox being checked.

Any ideas on how to fix this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you post of demonstration of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/G95Td/3/ 
It does get checked in jsfiddle for some reason.

Comment: Are you halting the propagation of the event in the `onclick` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change your code (in the jsfiddle.net example) to something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/G95Td/7/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#click').click(function(event) {
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if (!$target.is(':input')) {
            // div and contents, except inputs
            alert('click');
        } else {
            // div's content inputs
        }
    });
});
```